Probability in canonical ensemble
I have a doubt on the following exercise on canonical ensemble.
We have N indistinguishable and independent particles in 2 dimensions subjected to the following potential:
$V(x,y)= \begin{cases}
0 & \|(x,y)\| \le R \\
\alpha (R - \|(x,y)\|)^2 & \|(x,y)\| > R \\
\end{cases}$
so the Hamiltonian of the system can be written: $H=\sum_{i=1}^N[\frac{p_{i,x}^2 + p_{i,y}^2}{2m}+V(x_i,y_i)].$
Calculate the value $T^*$ for which the probability of finding one particle inside the circumference of radius R is equal to 1/4.
The solution for the probability is $P=\frac{1}{Z_1}\int dp_{1,x}dp_{1,y}\int_{\|(x,y)\|>R}e^{-\beta H} $ where $Z_1$ is the partition function for one particle.
My doubt is: why we integrate out of the circle to calculate the probability of finding particle into the circle?
Thanks.
